# How can Python give dfferent results for the same data set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running the code below.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('C:\\path\\Recon.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('C:\\path\\data.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for neighbor in root.iter('outputColumn'):
        writer.writerow(neighbor.attrib)
        print(neighbor.attrib)
```

In the console window I see this:

```
{'refId': 'Package\\RAW DATA PORTFOLIO SPLIT\\Sequence Container\\RAW DATA WHOLESALE\\TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_P_WHOLESALE.Outputs[OLE DB Destination Error Output].Columns[ErrorColumn]', 'dataType': 'i4', 'lineageId': 'Package\\RAW DATA PORTFOLIO SPLIT\\Sequence Container\\RAW DATA WHOLESALE\\TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_P_WHOLESALE.Outputs[OLE DB Destination Error Output].Columns[ErrorColumn]', 'name': 'ErrorColumn', 'specialFlags': '2'}
```

In the text file I see this:

```
refId,dataType,lineageId,name,specialFlags
```

What gets printed is exactly right.  I would expect to see the same thing in the text file, but it is completely different.  How can I get the writer to write what is being printed?

Comment: If what gets printed is exactly right there isn't any need to put it through the csv writer. Can you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: its amazing to see how a not-so-clear-question gets such a fast and good answer - you got a love SO !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`neighbor.attrib` is a `dict`. `writerow` takes an arbitrary iterable, and `iter(neighbor.attrib)` returns the *keys* of the `dict`. `print`, on the other hand, doesn't expect an iterable argument; it just turns it into a string.

It's not clear what you expect `writer.writerow` to produce, though. Perhaps just the values? In that case, use

```
ordered_keys = ["refId", "dataType", "lineageId", "name", "specialFlags"]  # Or whatever order you want
for neighbor in root.iter('outputColumn'):
     writer.writerow([neighbor.attrib[k] for k in ordered_keys])
```

Another option is

```
ordered_keys = ["refId", "dataType", "lineageId", "name", "specialFlags"]  # Or whatever order you want
values_of = operator.itemgetter(*ordered_keys)
for neighbor in root.iter('outputColumn'):
     writer.writerow(values_of(neighbor.attrib))
```

Simplest, though, is to use `csv.DictWriter`; they you *can* pass your `dict` to `writerow` directly.

```
ordered_keys = ...
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ordered_keys)
for neighbor in root.iter('outputColumn'):
    writer.writerow(neighbor.attrib)
```

Comment: There's no guarantee `neighbor.attrib.values()` will come out in the order the questioner wanted, though. Explicitly imposing an order with something like `[neighbor.attrib[key] for key in order]` would likely be a good idea.

Comment: or `csv.DictWriter`?

Comment: I forgot about `DictWriter`.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea what was going on.  Now it makes a lot more sense.  Thanks everyone!!